# Local class as Template Argument - Point of Instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, generics, instantiation

I am trying to wrap my head around example from TC++PL, 4th edition (p.751).

```
void fff()
{
    struct S { int a,b; };
    vector<S> vs;
    // ...
}
```

From the discussion, it follows that the point of instantiation of `vector<S>` is just before the definition of `void fff()`. However, `struct S` is not visible outside `void fff()`. What is proper way to think of the instantiation point with local classes as template arguments?

Answer (score 2):

What is meant with instantiation is **template instantiation** in this case.

The compiler creates a vector class definition of vector just before fff so it can be reused if another instantiation needs to be done with S later on.
It does not create an instance of vector at that point.

Yes, we can't access S from outside fff but the compiler knows about it and create a global template so it can be reused.

see

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template

Comment: Thank you! I think I can reformulate my question. Is it correct that the statement that template classes are instantiated just before the declaration containing its use is just a heuristic applied only to names used inside template definition but not to the template arguments?

Comment: That is, it only relates to the binding of dependent and independent names, but not to the template argument

Comment: Don't know if thats in the standard, templates get instantiated when their types are complete and globally. Maybe compiler builders are allowed to do whatever suits them best in this case